# Android: How Monkey detects crashes and ANR

Tags: android, xamarin.android

1. How to avoid ANR and crashes through monkey.
2. How to send events
   through Monkey server(e.g. inject events (tap, keys, etc…) from app
   that is running on device)

   Any suggestion or help?...

Thanks

Comment: What is this Monkey you are talking about?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html Monkey used for Automatic test an application by sending random events.

Answer (score 0):

Well you found the documentation for how to use Monkey. To execute Monkey commands from you application I think you would need to invoke shell commands, which is described in this blog post: http://shreyagarwal.blog.com/2011/04/20/executing-shell-commands-in-android-applications/

Avoiding ANR's is up to you, you will need to figure out what causes them. Just keep intensive tasks out of the UI thread and you will be good to go for the most of the time.